# Safari's getBoundingClientRect() Implementation Returns Incorrect Top

Tags: javascript, dom, safari, getboundingclientrect

I have a `div` with `float: right` and I'm trying to get its distance from the top of the viewport. In every browser except Safari I'm getting the expected results from `element.getBoundingClientRect().top`. Safari appears to be reporting the element's distance from the top of the page rather than the viewport. This is contrary to what is defined in the [spec for this method](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-element-getboundingclientrect) (as I understand it). Is Safari just not following the rules here, or are other browsers being more forgiving of some mistake of mine that I'm not seeing?

Comment: do you get the same in other "mobile" browsers?

Comment: This is not on Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that effects the way that Safari reports element and scroll locations on its load event. If you run the exact same call with a 500ms timeout everything works as expected.

I will update when I hear back on my bug report.

Comment: Have you received any response?

Comment: @RomanSnitko Nope. Not a peep in 5 years. I have not checked recently to see if it still is an issue. Here is the ticket: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/5842026

Comment: this solution didn't work for me, but adding an empty <script> tag at the end of body did.

Comment: This solution worked for me (y). Either add 500ms or `addEventListeners('load', () => {}` before running my function. Empty script tag did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, and the 500ms tricks doesn't solve it for me.

What did the job is to add a script (any script, even an empty one) at the end of body.

Such as :

```
[...]
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //content doesn't matter
  </script>
</body>
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try awaiting the fonts ready global promise:

```
document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
   const {top} = element.getBoundingClientRect();
})
```